# How to keep leading zeros in for-loop range

Tags: bash

I have a directory containing many subdirectories (named 0001, 0002...), and I want to start a bash script running in each directory.

```
for i in {0001..0021}; do cd $i; ../script1.sh; cd ..; done
```

With the above it ignores the 000 and takes the range as 1 to 21. How do I get it to take the 0's into account?

Comment: bash version `4.2.45(2)` `{0001..0021}` just gives what you want.

Comment: @Kent: Bash version `4.2.45(2)` here, `echo {0001..0021}` gives `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @nneonneo strange.... I was not lying... :D   check this: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html search `Supplied integers` and read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in {1..21}; do
    i=`printf '%04d' $i`
    # do stuff with $i (now in the format 0001)
done
```

Comment: Or `i=$(printf '%04d' $i)`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to start a bash script running in **each directory**.

Then you can simply use `*`

```
for i in *; do cd $i; ../script1.sh; cd ..; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `((...))` in BASH:

```
for ((i=0; i<=21; i++)); do j=$(printf "%04d" $i); cd $j; ../script1.sh; cd ..; done
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way of doing this ( my way and fastest )

```
 for i in 000{1..21}; do cd ${i:(-4)}; ../script1.sh; cd ..; done
```